# Firefox type rendering bolder than other OS X browsers - is there a solution?

Tags: fonts, cross-browser, text-rendering, typekit

Are there any non-hacky html/css/jquery tricks to achieve better font rendering for Firefox users? The screenshots below (Safari 5/Chrome 20/Firefox 13) show that Firefox is rendering user-agent fonts as well as typekit served fonts much bolder.

User-agent font (Helvetica)
[image: User-agent font (Helvetica)]

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0.025em;
color: #333;
```

Typekit-served font (Meta)
[image: Typekit-served font (Meta)]

```
font-family: "ff-meta-web-pro", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 0.025em;
color: #333;
```

And in both cases these font sizes get used for h1, h2 and p:

```
font-size: 1.4em;

font-size: 1.1em;

font-size: 0.75em;
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: @Neil I put the CSS in the edited question...

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS reset before you do your css:

- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/
- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which OS you are using, but it looks as if Firefox is using ClearType rather than standard grey-scale antialiasing.

Comment: The OS was mentioned in the question headline ;) All 6 screenshots were done from OS X browsers. Wasn't ClearType brought in with Microsoft's Windows XP? I got my hands on older Apple laptops with older Safari, Chrome and Firefoxes - same thing: Firefox renders much bolder :(

Comment: Sorry, I completely overlooked the title there, oops! I don't know whether the Mac has an equivalent to ClearType.

Comment: Spent an entire night and day; looks like one just has to live with Firefox's rickety rendering.